# How to replace scenes when clicked on imageview in cocos2d-android

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-engine, cocos2d-android, scene

i have started to develope an game app using cocos2d-android game engine, til now had put 4 imageview and a background image to the scene1, now if clicked on 1st imageview it should navigate to the next scene, i googled and youtube for this but did not succeeded, and also there is no more sources for cocos2d android game engine.

Answer (score 1):

Make your image as menuItem and change your scene on the click method of that menuItem as below

```
    CCMenuItem  menuItem1 = CCMenuItemImage.item("backbtn.png", "backbtn.png", this,
            "onClickMenuItem");
```

then handle the onClick method of this menuItem as below

```
    public void onClickMenuItem(Object menuItem) {
    if (menuItem == menuItem1) {
        CCDirector.sharedDirector().popScene();

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CCMenu and CCMenuItemImage or CCMenuItemSprite. You can set method that will be called on menu item click.